# VBA convert time

Tags: vba, time

I need to convert time from 14:54 to a double 14+54/60. And i do this with the following code:

```
Private Function Omzetten(ByVal time As String) As Double
Dim min As Integer, hours As Integer, datum As Date
datum = CDate(time)
min = DatePart("n", datum)
hours = DatePart("h", datum)
Omzetten = hours + min / 60
End Function
```

But when the time is 26:00 he only gives 2 because 26-24 is 2. So I thought to ad day = DatePart("d", datum), but then he always gives day = 30. Does anyone has a solution?

Comment: 26:00 is not a valid time? But add much more detail, if you do want to accept 26:00 as in 26 hours you'll need your own routines instead of just using built-ins that expect a valid time of day.

Comment: As a hint you'll want to seperate the strings either side of the colon (assuming you don't want seconds), convert to a number and then do your calculation so 30:10 is valid.

Comment: Yeah you're right, it's not time but a duration of a certain cycle. So 26 is valid. But I don't know what you mean by "your own routines instead of just using built-ins that expect a valid time of day". I'm quite new with vba

Comment: I already tried to take for example Right(14:54,2) but the problem is that the time 14:54 is then a string and is given as 0,356243 (or something like that). So you don't get 54 but 43

Comment: why convert to a DateTime at all? See my example below.

Comment: I solved the problem. time was Worksheets("Values").Cells(valrij, 2).Value and then I had the problem with the time that was converted to a string and became 0,0347222. But I had tot use Worksheets("Values").Cells(valrij, 2).Text :-)
Thanks for the help!

Comment: multiply the value by 24. don't change it to a string first. the display in the cell does not matter, as it is stored in excel's time format (a fractional value) internally.

Answer (score 2):

if its always in the format `hours : mins` then use the below:

```
Dim str As String
Dim strSplit() As String
Dim Val As Double

str = "26:00"
strSplit = Split(str, ":")

Val = CInt(strSplit(0)) + CInt(strSplit(1)) / 60
```

Comment: I know that, but the problem is when I take the value out of the cells and convert it to a string that 26:00 becomes 0,0347222222 and I can't do this with the 0,0347222222..

Comment: yes because you are formatting the cell as General which is being implicitly typed as Date which is not what you want (as you will get the fraction of a day). Instead format the cell(s) as text and everything will work.

Comment: I think you should write CInt(strSplit(1)) / 60

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, I used VB.Net which from above looks like it must be compatible with the newer VBA variants:

```
Private Function Omzetten(ByVal time As String) As Double
    Dim Hours As Integer = CInt(time.Substring(0, time.IndexOf(":")))
    Dim Minutes As Integer = CInt(time.Substring(time.IndexOf(":") + 1))
    Return Hours + Minutes / 60
End Function
```

Just as a note you might want to add some extra checks, the above code will for example fail on non-numeric input or if the time doesn't contain a colon. You might want something more like the following to cope with varying inputs:

```
Private Function Omzetten(ByVal time As String) As Double
    Dim Hours As Integer = 0
    Dim Minutes As Integer = 0
    Dim HoursStr As String
    If time.IndexOf(":") = -1 Then
        HoursStr = time
    Else
        HoursStr = time.Substring(0, time.IndexOf(":"))
    End If
    If IsNumeric(HoursStr) Then
        Hours = CInt(HoursStr)
    End If
    If time.IndexOf(":") >= 0 Then
        Dim MinutesStr As String = time.Substring(time.IndexOf(":") + 1)
        If IsNumeric(MinutesStr) Then
            Minutes = CInt(MinutesStr)
        End If
    End If
    Return Hours + Minutes / 60
End Function
```

Comment: It doesn't work. And I think it's the same problem as i had. Time as a string isn't hh:mm, it's a number 0,236728 so the code doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this with basic Excel formulas.

As times are stored as numbers if you divide any time by 1/24 (i.e. an hour) you'll get the answer as a double.

**Note** - if you want to use times over 24 hrs (e.g. 26:00) then set the cell custom format to **`[h]:mm:ss`**

*Examples*

```
    A        B
1   14:54    =A1/(1/24) // = 14.9
2   26:00    =A1/(1/24) // = 26.0
```

Does this help?

Comment: No it doesn't help. I think it has something to do with the cell properties because it's on "custom" and when I change it to "general" it goes from "0:50" to 0,0347222222. So all of this doesn't work and this is why i'm stuck.

Comment: Why are you changing it to general? Can you not just set the format of the cells you are inputting times into as `[h]:mm:ss`?

Comment: But can you not set them to `[h]:mm:ss`? Who has set them as `h:mm`?

Comment: The person I got the file from. I can set it as h:mm:ss but then the problem stays the same, or not?

Comment: If you set the format as `[h]:mm:ss` then I think this solves your issue. Highlight your times, hit `CTRL + 1`, and update the custom format.